# "operator shared_ptr" method access? (librealsense)

Tags: c++, operators, shared-ptr, realsense, c-api

I´m currently trying to wrap the [LibRealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/include) into a Unreal 4 Plugin. This lib provides some C API as well as some C++ API (wrapping it´s C API), so I´m doing C++ (which makes sense for Unreal).

But there is a kind of operator overloading I´ve never seen before (in [rs_pipeline.hpp](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_pipeline.hpp#L508)):

```
class pipeline
{
public:

    pipeline(context ctx = context())
...
    operator std::shared_ptr<rs2_pipeline>() const
    {
        return _pipeline;
    }

private:
    context _ctx;
    std::shared_ptr<rs2_pipeline> _pipeline;
}
```

`rs2_pipeline` is the C-type of a pipeline, it is accessed in all the c++ classes as a shared pointer. E.g:

```
 class config
 {
 public:
 ...
     bool can_resolve(std::shared_ptr<rs2_pipeline> p) const
 ...
 }
```

So when I´m trying to call `config.can_resolve` with my C++ ´pipeline´
 object, I need to get the internal `shared_ptr<rs_pipline>`. But how do I call `operator shared_ptr<rs_pipline()`?? And what kind of operator is it exactly?

Comment: It's a [*user-defined conversion operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), also known as a "cast operator".

Comment: Thanks, now I know what it is! =)
In fact, my first try was just writing `config.can_resolve(pipeline)` without fully understanding what it is. But it didnt´work because my `pipline` was a pointer, so so the compiler said the types are incompetible.... 

Now it works with `config.can_resolve(*pipline)`